# Remove or re-index content for DuckDuckGo?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, search-engines, duckduckgo

Google has the "[remove outdated content tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7041154?hl=en)" to prompt it to rescan outdated content on a site you don't own. I have some content that I changed, and I would similarly like DuckDuckGo to re-index or remove the content.

The old content is in the index and has been outdated for a while. Is there a way to prompt DuckDuckGo to re-index/remove similar to how Google works?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I haven't been able to try it yet. I'm planning on trying it this weekend. Also, I'm not a newbie to SE, as I have more rep on other sites. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DuckDuckGo sources its results ["most commonly from Bing"](https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/sources/), so it can be useful to use Bing's removal tool to help get stuff off of DuckDuckGo.

[Bing Content Removal Tool](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/bing-content-removal-tool-cb6c294d)

As of 2021, DuckDuckGo has no native removal tools.